# Sensitivity Vs Positive Predicted Value - which is best?

Tags: statistics, classification, regression, ensemble-learning

I am trying to build a model on a class imbalanced dataset (binary - 1's:25% and 0's 75%). Tried with Classification algorithms and ensemble techniques. I am bit confused on below two concepts as i am more interested in predicting more 1's.

```
1. Should i give preference to Sensitivity or Positive Predicted Value. 
Some ensemble techniques give maximum 45% of sensitivity and low Positive Predicted Value.
And some give 62% of Positive Predicted Value and low Sensitivity.


2. My dataset has around 450K observations and 250 features. 
After power test i took 10K observations by Simple random sampling. While selecting 
variable importance using ensemble technique's the features 
are different compared to the features when i tried with 150K observations. 
Now with my intuition and domain knowledge i felt features that came up as important in 
150K observation sample are more relevant. what is the best practice?

3. Last, can i use the variable importance generated by RF in other ensemple 
techniques to predict the accuracy?
```

Can you please help me out as am bit confused on which w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preference between Sensitivity and Positive Predictive value depends on your ultimate goal of the analysis. The difference between these two values is nicely explained here: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat507/node/71/
Altogether, these are two measures that look at the results from two different perspectives. Sensitivity gives you a probability that a test will find a "condition" among those you have it. Positive Predictive value looks at the prevalence of the "condition" among those who is being tested.

Accuracy is depends on the outcome of your classification: it is defined as (true positive + true negative)/(total), not variable importance's generated by RF.

Also, it is possible to compensate for  the imbalances in the dataset, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/264798/random-forest-unbalanced-dataset-for-training-test

Comment: @Julian, thanks for your suggestions. The link is extremely good for my case.. besides in RF if class is imbalanced we can consider MeanDecreaseGini to select the variable importance.. one can stop when gin gets almost constant.. please correct if am wrong here...

Comment: "Our simulation studies show that for the randomForest function all three variable importance measures are unreliable, and the Gini importance is most strongly biased." from Strobl et.al "Bias in random forest variable importance measures: Illustrations, sources and a solution", BMC Bioinformatics20078:25,
https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25

  Consider using permutation importance instead.
 
  Altmann et.al. "Permutation importance: a corrected feature importance measure"  Bioinformatics, Volume 26, Issue 10, 15 May 2010, Pages 1340–1347, https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btq134

Comment: Sure Julian.. and thanks a lot for your replies.. after going thorough the links.. i felt i was completely wrong !!